# Testing MapStruct with Spring Boot 3 in Intellij

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, mapstruct

This has been asked before for other versions of Spring Boot, but I can't find a solution for Spring 3.

I'm trying to test a controller that uses mapstruct to return DTOs in IntelliJ. I've created a class to scan my entity package but it's not working:

```
@TestConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = EntityMapper.class)
public class MapperConfig {}
```

and

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest({SiteController.class, MapperConfig.class})
public class SiteControllerTests { .... }
```

I'm using gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct:1.5.5.Final'
    annotationProcessor 'org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.5.5.Final'
    ...
}
```

In my IntelliJ (2023.1.2) settings, I have "Enable annotation processing" enabled, and "Obtain processors from classpath". In my project structure settings, the mapstruct dependency is set to Provided. I also have the MapStruct plugin installed. My project also uses Lombok, which some answers said might be causing this somehow.

Despite all this, when I run my tests, I get the exception:

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type <my mapper type>
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing? The main project compiles fine.

**Update**
My mappers are:

```
public interface EntityMapper<D, E> {

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "updatedAt", ignore = true)
    void updateEntityFromDto(@MappingTarget E entity, D dto);

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "updatedAt", ignore = true)
    E fromDto(D dto);

    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "updatedAt", ignore = true)
    List<E> fromDto(List<D> dtoList);

    D toDto(E entity);

    List<D> toDto(List<E> entityList);
}
```

and

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface SiteMapper extends EntityMapper<SiteDto, Site> {

    @Override
    @Mapping(source = "user.id", target = "userId")
    SiteDto toDto(Site site);

    @Override
    // Prevent overwriting information
    @Mapping(target = "id", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "createdAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "updatedAt", ignore = true)
    @Mapping(target = "user", ignore = true)
    void updateEntityFromDto(@MappingTarget Site site, SiteDto siteDTO);
}
```

Comment: Can you please show your entire Mapper? I would guess that you are not using Springs component Model --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70982567/how-to-using-mapstruct-and-springboot-bean-together-autowired

Comment: I've added them @GJohannes

Answer (score 0):

No idea what the issue was. I created a new Spring project with Intellij then copied over my source and now it works, no `MapperConfig` required.